# Default Primary Key in GraphQL DynamoDB Schema?

Tags: react-native, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm creating my first schema for a new DynamoDB using graphql in AWS Amplify.  I noticed many examples where there is no @key directive to define the primary key such as "Product" below:

```
type Inventory @model
  @key(name: "byWarehouseID", fields: ["warehouseID"], queryField: "itemsByWarehouseID")
  @key(fields: ["productID", "warehouseID"]) {
  productID: ID!
  warehouseID: ID!
  inventoryAmount: Int!
}

type Product @model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  orders: [Order] @connection(keyName: "byProduct", fields: ["id"])
  inventories: [Inventory] @connection(fields: ["id"])
}
```

Is the first field automatically used as the primary key (partition key)?

Comment: Your question made me realize how poorly documented this behavior is, the closest I found was this article on Medium https://medium.com/@dantasfiles/exploring-the-backend-specifications-generated-by-aws-amplify-api-57be2a349fa9
Which states that it defaults to the id field, I guess it creates one if it doesn't exist, like it does for createdAt and updatedAt

Comment: @danielfranca that is a very helpful article, thanks!  I think because there are several technologies at play here, the documentation has gaps.  Anyway it seems like you've answered the question since checking the build\stacks\{category}.json in a local example does show that a new "id" key was created on a model that had "messageId" as the first field and no `@key` notation.  Please create an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question made me realize how poorly documented is this behavior.
The closest I found is in this article: https://medium.com/@dantasfiles/exploring-the-backend-specifications-generated-by-aws-amplify-api-57be2a349fa9

If you don't specify a key Amplify/AppSync does that for you, creating an `id` field
Like it does with other fields (i.e: `createdAt`, `updatedAt`)

> Because no default @key annotation was specified, the AccountRepresentative table has the default id partition/hash key.

Comment: I came here from that article. Note that there is no way to specify the default @key annotation :)